# Will lock_guards instantiated as RValues work in C++?

Tags: c++, synchronization

In C++, stack objects are typically created in order of appearance and destroyed in the opposite order when they go out of scope.

However, this only applies to LValues, not RValues, as demonstrated [on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Eh43TqG6a) with this code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
class C{
    int instanceNo;
    public:
    C(){ 
        static int instanceCount = 0;
        instanceNo = ++instanceCount;
        std::cout << "constructed " << instanceNo << "\n";
    }
    ~C(){ 
        std::cout << "destructed " << instanceNo << "\n";
    }
};
int main()
{
    C one;
    C two;
    C{}; // three as RValue
    C four;
    C five;
}
```

Result: The RValue is destroyed immediately, not at the end of the `main()`. So far, that's fine for me.

We had some C++14 code like this:

```cpp
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mutex);
```

With C++17 we can use template argument deduction (CTAD) and shorten the code to

```cpp
std::lock_guard guard(mutex);
```

However, a colleague made it even shorter:

```cpp
std::lock_guard{mutex};
```

In my understanding, this is an RValue now. It will lock the mutex at construction, which is fine. However, according to above demo, its lifetime ends immediately, thus unlocking the mutex and effectively removing the protection.

Is this conclusion correct and that change breaks the thread-safety of our class?

Comment: I believe you are misinterpreting what the _scope_ of `C{};` is.  The scope is not main().  It's that one line.  Same goes for `std::lock_guard{mutex};`

Comment: @DrewDormann: okay, so you agree with me that such a lock_guard is nonsense and breaks the thread-safety.

Comment: It's nonsense.  Not necessarily because of lvalue/rvalue status, but because the scope of that object ends when `;` is reached.  `{ std::lock_guard guard(mutex); }` would have the same (bad) effect, as an lvalue.

Comment: `std::lock_guard{mutex};` -- I've made this typo many times. Yes, it doesn't add anything to thread safety.

Comment: @DrewDormann: agreed. With developers thinking about scope beginning at `{` and ending at `}`, it's a bit more obvious that `guard` in your version goes out of scope. The version with just `;` is not so visible.

Comment: But, to address the question in the title, rvalueness isn't the issue; it's lifetime. `void f(std::lock_guard{mutex});` can provide thread safety, because the guard exists throughout the execution of `f`.

Comment: @PeteBecker: okay, I see and agree. I never saw that construct, but of course, syntactically such a thing would work. It is an RValue outside f(). Is it an LValue inside f(), because it has been assigned a name (the parameter name)?

Comment: I have used a temporary `lock_guard` to protect just a single assignment: `lock_guard{mtx}, dest = compute();` protects `compute()` and the assignment, and starting with C++17 `(lock_guard{mtx}, dest) = compute();` protects only the assignment, but not `compute()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short: your analysis is 100% correct.

If you want to specifically test `std::lock_guard`: it requires only a class that implements `.lock()` and `.unlock()`, so you can create a dummy lock that just prints debug output yourself:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>

struct dummy_mutex
{  
    void lock()
    {
        std::cout << "Locked!\n" << std::flush;
    }

    void unlock()
    {
        std::cout << "Unlocked!\n" << std::flush;
    }
}; 
   
int main()
{  
    dummy_mutex mtx;

    std::cout << "A\n" << std::flush;
    {
        std::cout << "B\n" << std::flush;
        std::lock_guard{mtx};
        std::cout << "C\n" << std::flush;
    }
    std::cout << "D\n" << std::flush;

    return 0;
}
```

This prints:

```
A
B
Locked!
Unlocked!
C
D
```

If you change the line to `std::lock_guard guard{mtx};`, the output changes to:

```
A
B
Locked!
C
Unlocked!
D
```

Comment: That's an awesome idea! This will be 100% convincing.

Comment: Also, I just remembered: starting with C++20 constructors can be declared `[[nodiscard]]` to avoid this specific pitfall. Jason Turner did a [video about just this issue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E_ROB_xUQQQ). (Unfortunately as far as I'm aware the standard library doesn't yet have that attribute set for the constructors of `lock_guard` or similar, even in the newest standards.)

Comment: Hmm, and we can't ref-qualify the destructor, so it can't throw an exception if it's an RValue. Quite a pitfall, I'd say.

Comment: Mixing lvalue/rvalue with the concept of a destructor does not make sense at all. A destructor destroys an **object**, while rvalue/lvalue apply to expressions or variables. Also, throwing an exception would definitely not be the right move here, as that's runtime behavior, but this is definitely something that can easily be detected at compile time. Hence the addition of ``[[nodiscard]]`` constructors in C++20, it's just unfortunate that the standards committee hasn't come around to adding the attribute to all relevant constructors in the standard yet...